# SSRS Reportbuilder 3.0 Accessing row visibility

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have created a very simple report that is being used as a subreport. It is a single matrix with very little data in it.

[image]

I need to be able to toggle the rows based on a parameter that comes from the main report. I am able to toggle the visibility of the second and third row without issue but I am unable to access the row visibility for the first row.

[image]

I have found how to toggle the Hidden property based on an expression but it seems to only hide the row but it still shows whitespace

[image]

How am I able to access the row visibility for the top row so I can render it properly in the main report?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its hard to tell from the screen shots but I would guess that particular row is part of a row group. If it's in a row group then that group could span several rows so you cannot hide it.